# DBT full refresh drops all my materialized views. Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, dbt

We're using DBT to manage our data pipeline. We're also using postgres as our db. I'm creating some materialized views through a query (not in dbt) and it looks like whenever we run `dbt run --full-refresh` it drops those materialized views. Any idea why, and how to not drop the materialized views?

Comment: Can you share a bit more about the setup? 

Are you building materialized views in a DBT managed schema? 
Tree structure of your database would be helpful here. 

What about the DBT instance itself - have you set the schema that the existing materialized views in as a source?

Answer (score 4):

This answer came from Claire at DBT.

"If the materialized views depend on the upstream table, they will get dropped by the drop table my_table cascade statement"

This came from Jake at DBT.
"postgres views/materialized views are binding. There’s no opt-out and recreating them even in the same dbt run will result in periods where it’s not available."

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/rules-materializedviews.html
https://docs.getdbt.com/

Comment: Additional color here: `--full-refresh` effectively means that the schema (the target schema of the dbt environment) is dropped and everything on it will be re-created by DBT. @user2491463 Is creating the materialized view on a schema separate from the dbt target schema an option?

Answer (score 1):

As the previous answer stated, materialised views are dropped when a table is dropped because of the cascade.

A bridge towards getting higher uptime is to have tables which act as copies of the dbt tables which are being rebuilt which are then deleted and updated on rebuild.

The downtime whilst the tables are being rebuilt is probably worth the deterministic behaviour of knowing when the tables are being rebuilt, rather than having the materialised views disappearing during a long rebuild.

This is the macro I wrote to solve this problem. It creates a new table with a slightly different name within a single transaction, allowing for 100% uptime.

```
{% macro create_table(table_name) %}

{% set sql %}
    BEGIN;
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {{ table_name[:-4]}};
    CREATE TABLE {{ table_name[:-4]}} AS SELECT * FROM {{ table_name }};

    COMMIT;
{% endset %}

{% do run_query(sql) %}
{% do log(table_name+" table created", info=True) %}
{% endmacro %}
```